# How to use a session variable of one page to initialize another page's global variable in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 web pages. In the first webpage I have a text box which takes an user input.The number of controls rendered in the second page is based on the user input in the first page.
I am storing the user input from the first page as a session variable

```
Session("NoOfControlsToGenerate") = TextBox1.Text
```

Now, I wish to use this session variable in the next page for initializing a global variable and what I tried to do is

```
Dim num_Invitees As Integer = CType(Session("NoOfControlsToGenerate"), Integer)
```

But this gives me a NullReferenceException.

Can someone please suggest me what exactly I should be doing in order to use the session variable to initialize a global variable and also why the session variable's value is null while using outside a function but works fine when used inside a function?Thanks in advance

Thank You

Comment: ViewState is not the same as Session...

Comment: Session state is stored by the server, ViewState is stored by the browser.

Comment: What you proabably want to do is pass the number of invitees as part of the request, perhaps in the query string. Then you will have no state to worry about.

Comment: I am sorry about that. I was trying everything possible and tried replacing the Session variable using View State in both the pages and  pasted the wrong code in the question.

Comment: @Jodrell : I tried passing it through th query string and now I get this "HttpException : Request is not available in this context" . The problem is that I want to initialize the "numInvitees" outside the page_init method because, I have to create an array of text boxes which I am using in another method(which is being invoked on clicking the submit button). Is it not possible to do this? I am very new to vb.net and is just getting familiarized with whats what.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.net makes passing such parameters deceptively easy. If you're posting back to the same page, you'll be able to simply read the value of the textbox, which will persist across the postback by default.

If you're posting to another page, you can use

```
CType(Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("YourTextBoxID"), TextBox).Text
```